# Edit hidden records in frontend

Tags: typo3

I am building an extension to edit tt_news records in frontend. 
I set `setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE)` in my repository.
But if I try edit a hidden record, I get the error

> Object with identity „12345" not found.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the PropertyMapping. If extbase try to assign an uid (12345) to an Domain Object (tt_news) the "setEnableFields" setting of the Repository isn't respected. So you must fetch the object by yourself.

the simple solution is to do this in an initialize*Action for each "show" action. For editAction an example:

```
public function initializeEditAction() {
  if ($this->request->hasArgument('news')) {
    $newsUid = $this->request->getArgument('news');

    if (!$this->newsRepository->findByUid($newsUid)) {
      $defaultQuerySettings = $this->newsRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
      $defaultQuerySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);
      $this->newsRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);

      if ($news = $this->newsRepository->findByUid($newsUid)) {
        $this->request->setArgument('news', $news);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Hard Part is to get the object to update. As I never try this I have found an TypeConverter to fetch also hidden Records at https://gist.github.com/helhum/58a406fbb846b56a8b50

Maybe Instead to register the TypeConverter for everything (like the example in `ext_localconf.php`) you can try to assign it only in the `initializeUpdateAction`

```
public function initializeUpdateAction() {
  if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('news')) {
    $this->arguments->getArgument('news')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
      ->setTypeConverter('MyVendor\\MyExtension\\Property\\TypeConverters\\MyPersistenObjectConverter')
  }
}
```

Comment: You first solution will work, but in the updateAction we must get the newsUid by $this->request->getArgument('news')['__identity‘].

Nest I will test the TypeConverter solution. Thanks!

Comment: And the TypeCpnverter at https://gist.github.com/helhum/58a406fbb846b56a8b50 will also work great for me!

Answer (score 2):

I am **guessing** you are using an action like

```
/**
 * Single view of a news record
 *
 * @param \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\News $news news item
 */
public function detailAction(\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\News $news = null)
```

Your problem is, that the `Repository` is **not** used to fetch the record.

---

As a solution, remove the argument, clear the caches and try something like that

```
/**
 * Single view of a news record
 *
 * @param \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\News $news news item
 */
public function detailAction() {
    $id = (int)$this->request->getArgument('news');
    if ($id) {
        $news = $this->newsRepository->findByUid($previewNewsId);
    }
}
```

Now you can manipulate the `QuerySettings` and use those.

Comment: Ok. So I can open the edit-form. But the updateAction wil

Comment: without any code and error message, nobody can help you further. Sorry